# Tensorflow 1.x: Converting tf.variable (state_ops) to a tf.constant

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have this old tensorflow code here that I want to improve a bit.
It includes a custom made (Adabelief) Optimizer.
The Optimizer keeps tracks of iterations which are stored in a tf.variable and updated through:

```
..... other code
updates += [ state_ops.assign_add( self.iterations, 1) ]
........ other code
return control_flow_ops.group(*updates, name=self.name+'_updates')
```

in the main optimizer function.

So the problem is, the actual main program also keeps tracks of iterations
And allows them to reset but that makes the counters shift.
So my idea was to pass the iteration count from the main program to the Optimizer and calculate an offset which is then subtracted from the iteration counter in the Optimizer.
But for this to work I need to "snapshot" the value of the iteration counter in a tf.constant(?).
But doing:

```
iters_optimizer = tf.constant(OptimizerIterations)
```

Results in:

```
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.ops.variables.RefVariable'> to Tensor. Contents: <tf.Variable 'src_dst_opt/iters:0' shape=() dtype=int64_ref>. Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

How can I create a static/constant value from this counter?
And I can't introduce new tf.variables as this would break model compatibility(?).